# How can I count XML string elements in a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem:

> Write a function, `tag_count`, that takes as its argument a list of
>   strings. It should return a count of how many of those strings are XML
>   tags. You can tell if a string is an XML tag if it begins with a left
>   angle bracket "<" and end with a right angle bracket ">".

def tag_count(tokens):
    count = 0
    for token in tokens:
        if token[0] == '<' and token[-1] == '>':
            count += 1
    return count
    list1 = ['', 'Hello World!', '']
    count = tag_count(list1)
    print("Expected result: 2, Actual result: {}".format(count))

My results are always `0`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for count, xml_list in enumerate(xml_list)
    if str(xml_list).startwith("<") and str(xml_list).endswith(">")
       print(count)
```

#xml tag list counter

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are not counting anything since you are redefining `count` variable in the loop. Also, you are actually missing the XML string check (starts with `<` and ends with `>`).

Fixed version:

```
def tag_count(list_strings):
    count = 0
    for item in list_strings:
        if item.startswith("<") and item.endswith(">"):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Which you may then improve by using the built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
def tag_count(list_strings):
    return sum(1 for item in list_strings
               if item.startswith("<") and item.endswith(">"))
```

Comment: The same answer just wanted to post, but you posted early.

Answer (score 1):

```
    def tag_count(xml_count):
        count = 0
        for xml in xml_count:
            if xml[0] == '<' and xml[-1] == '>':
                count += 1
        return count


# This is by using positional arguments
# in python. You first check the zeroth
# element, if it's a '<' and then the last
# element, if it's a '>'. If True, then increment 
# variable 'count'.
```